# UIWebView - shouldStartLoadWithRequest - NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have an UIWebView embeded in my app. What I am doing is, add an header (to be specific, authorization header), to all requests made from it.

This event is fired when a URL opens from an HTML iframe BUT it does not seem to be able to add header to that request.

To be sure, I added a log entry in this event and it does well but if I monitor HTTP traffic using burpsuite, it's not adding header.

Has anybody encountered such issue ever? Any possible workaround?

Below is my code, if it helps.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    [(NSMutableURLRequest *)request addBasicAuth:self.accountObj.Username     andPassword:self.accountObj.Password];
    NSLog(@"!Request URL :%@",[request URL]);
    NSLog(@"!Request Header :%@",[request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a header to your actual request, why dont you create a new one?

Cancel that one, and throw a new one

Comment: I tried following code but I am doing it somewhat wrong. It assigns that request to main UIWebView, instead of inside iframe. How can I fix that?

Comment: prevUrlString = [NSString stringWithString:[[request URL] absoluteString]];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
    [urlRequest addBasicAuth:self.accountObj.Username andPassword:self.accountObj.Password];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];